# bind(this) not working on ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I use react and jQuery. here's a part of my code.

Before react component mounts, I perform ajax request to know if user is logged in.

It is supposed to set state when a response returns status code 200.
am I incorrectly using `bind(this)`?

```
componentWillMount: function(){
  $.ajax({
     url: "/is_signed_in",
     method: "GET",
     dataType: "json"
  }).success(function(response){
    this.setState({ signedIn: response.signed_in, currentUser: $.parseJSON(response.current_user) });
  }.bind(this));
},
componentDidMount: function(){
  console.log(this.state.signedIn);
}
```

---

**Edit 01**

when I do `console.log(this);` in `success(function(response){...})` callback.

`this` was the below.

```
R…s.c…s.Constructor {props: Object, context: Object, state: Object, refs: Object, _reactInternalInstance: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper}_reactInternalInstance: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper_context: Object_currentElement: ReactElement_instance: ReactClass.createClass.Constructor_isOwnerNecessary: false_isTopLevel: false_mountImage: null_mountIndex: 0_mountOrder: 2_pendingCallbacks: null_pendingElement: null_pendingForceUpdate: false_pendingReplaceState: false_pendingStateQueue: null_renderedComponent: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper_rootNodeID: ".0"_warnedAboutRefsInRender: false__proto__: ReactCompositeComponentWrappercontext: Object__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: get __proto__()set __proto__: set __proto__()getDOMNode: ()__reactBoundArguments: null__reactBoundContext: ReactClass.createClass.Constructor__reactBoundMethod: ()arguments: (...)bind: (newThis )caller: (...)length: 0name: ""__proto__: ()[[TargetFunction]]: ()[[BoundThis]]: ReactClass.createClass.Constructor[[BoundArgs]]: Array[0]props: Objectrefs: Object__proto__: ObjectrenderButtonSet: ()setSignedIn: ()__reactBoundArguments: null__reactBoundContext: ReactClass.createClass.Constructor__reactBoundMethod: setSignedIn(response)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "setSignedIn"prototype: setSignedIn__proto__: ()<function scope>arguments: (...)bind: (newThis )arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: ""prototype: boundMethod.bind__proto__: ()<function scope>caller: (...)length: 1name: ""__proto__: ()[[TargetFunction]]: setSignedIn(response)[[BoundThis]]: ReactClass.createClass.Constructor[[BoundArgs]]: Array[0]state: ObjectcurrentUser: Objectcreated_at: "2015-07-24T18:30:38.772+09:00"email: "admin@gmail.com"facebook_account_url: nullfirstName: "유찬"github_account_url: nullgoogleplus_account_url: nullid: 1lastName: "서"linkedin_account_url: nullsns_avatar: nulltwitter_account_url: nullupdated_at: "2015-08-14T02:14:21.091+09:00"__proto__: ObjectsignedIn: true__proto__: Object__proto__: ReactClassComponent
```

---

**Solutions**
My code above was antipattern.
Follow one of the methods suggested by Answer i adopted. 
Plus, React documentation already provided very useful solution about my case: [Load Initial Data via AJAX](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)

Also, setState is asynchronous.
That's why I thought setState not working when I log it on console.
After all, i checked inside render and pass as props to child components.

Comment: If you just log `this` to console, you can easily see exactly what it is.

Comment: On a side note: It's not a good idea to asynchronously setState inside componentWillMount as this can cause a rendering race condition.

Comment: khuderm - I updated my question.
MikeDriver - what is your recommendation to perform the action then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use an Ajax call for setState in componentWillMount; **do it in componentDidMount**.

If you don't want to do the first render before you're having data **AND** those data are just for initialization perform your call outside and on success  render your view with the fetched data =====>

```
<Myview data={initialDataFromTheCallSuccess} /> and then put it in getInitialState
```

Read this if you choose this path (cause as stated in the doc this is not an anti-pattern on certain conditions): https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

hope it helps

**Edit:**
There is two way to do it the first one you fetch outside your react class

```
  $.ajax({...}).success(function(res) {
      <MyView data={res} /> // render your function on success
  });
```

and in MyView you getInitialState from props "data".
Use this method only if you need to call your get once (read the anti-pattern stuff).

Other method is doing what you are doing but in componentDidMount.
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Hope it's clearer

Comment: I did not quite 100% get your meaning. Then how do I exactly send get request in `componenetDidMount`? and should I pass `this.state.signedIn` to child components as props? Could you show me any sample code?

Comment: Thank you Richard. I think you mean the second method as this tip provided by React Docs, https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Comment: I never read this tip but that's exactly what I meant :) I added it to my answer for others

Comment: lol but.. still bind(this) not working tho.. although `this.state.signedIn` is still `null`.

Comment: setState is asynchronous, console.log in render or in setState callback setState({...}, function() { console.log(this.state);});
For the binding I don't know check it's written properly and that you're really receiving something :)